# Valgrind: Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation (malloc)

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to find the error in the following bit of code. When I run the program with Valgrind I'm getting the error stating. Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation (malloc)

```
    int main(){

    int **point;
    int val=3;
    int i;
    int j;

    point=malloc(sizeof(int*)*val);

    for(i=0;i<val;i++){
        point[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    }
    for(i=0;i<val;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            point[i][j]=point[i][j]+i*j+val;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your posted program looks fine other than required headers are missing and the allocated memory are not freed. The problem should be using the allocated and uninitialized data in the originally followed code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This ends at line 13, is there anything extra (like any included headers) that you haven't included here?

Comment: Is the *posted* code producing the specified error? If not, then it cannot be considered [mcve].

Comment: Note that valgrind normally reports the line where the access to the uninitialized value occurred, *as well as* the line where the memory was allocated.  It seems like you might be focusing on the second one, but you've left out the first one (which probably is after this point, in the code you didn't show).

Comment: "*Valgrind tells me ...*" best post the complete message Valgrind is giving.

Comment: Yes, I have not included the header files, I will update the code to have all contents

Comment: The code has been updated and the valgrind output was added

Comment: `sptr` is used without being declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the value `point[i][j]` without initializing here:

```
        point[i][j]=point[i][j]+i*j+val;
```

The initial value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` is indeterminate and using the value invokes *undefined behavior*.

You can use [`calloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of `malloc()` to have it initialize the allocated buffer to zero:

```
for(i=0;i<val;i++){
    point[i]=calloc(4, sizeof(int));
}
```

Another way is initializing the buffer manually:

```
for(i=0;i<val;i++){
    point[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        point[i][j]=0; /* or put what you like */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The part of the valgrind message you originally quoted just tells you where uninitialized memory was allocated.  The full message you've now posted tells you where that uninitialized value was used:

```
for(i=0;i<val;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        point[i][j]=point[i][j]+i*j+val;
    }
}
```

Here you're reading from `point[i][j]` which has not yet been initialized.